# Weird problem in .htacess occurring after server change

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site with 3 scripts, namely `viewgames.php`, `play.php` and `users.php` present at the root directory. I also have a .htaccess file in the same (root) directory.

My .htaccess code that cleans URLs is :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./viewgames.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ ./viewgames.php?cat=$1
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ ./users.php?action=$1
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)$ ./play.php?gn=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

When I was developing in localhost (XAMPP), I got no problem in accessing the clean URLs (using the above htaccess code) such as `localhost/MySite/play/foo`, `localhost/MySite/category/action`, `localhost/MySite/search/lolol` or `localhost/MySite/users/myaccount`.

It clearly means that the above .htaccess code was working like a charm in my localhost server. Then I uploaded the above code to a shared Apache-based linux server, and encountered some *weird* problems -

- `https://example.com/category/blabla` was working fine, and so was `https://example.com/search/blabla`
- But the URLs `https://example.com/play/xyz` and `https://example.com/users/anyaction` stopped working. By that I mean, the page was loading fine, the site was there, but no `$_GET` values were passed to the PHP script. Thus, I am not able to get the value of parametes `gn` and `action`. (*see above code*)
- I even tried by `var_dump`-ing the `$_GET` array in the scripts, and they returned an empty array, meaning that no values were sent to the script.

Please check my .htaccess code. I am completely and utterly new to .htaccess, and the above code is merely a copied one. I will really appreciate any help in the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ viewgames.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ viewgames.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ users.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^play/(.*)$ play.php?gn=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

It is important to keep `MultiViews` options off to avoid content negotiation feature causing issues for `mod_rewrite` module.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly the answer I was looking for. People like you are the reason I love StackOverflow so much.